# How can I test in Production Facebook page with test data showing for tester of the app only

Tags: facebook, chatbot

I have developed a chatbot which is only used to send a private message to user who leave specific key word on our particular facebook post on my Facebook page.

I want to have a pre-production test in my Production page. Please let me know how can I test with data not displaying to public but only display to the tester of the app and the page admin.

Comment: and you are sure you can send him a message just because he left a comment? i thought that you can only send messages if the user interacted with your bot first.

Comment: @luschn probably talking about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/object/private_replies, I guess.

Comment: Make a page post via your app first maybe? (You’d have to ask for publish_pages permission to do that, but you don’t have to submit that for review afterwards if you don’t need it elsewhere.) Any content created by your app will only be visible to people with a role in your app, while your app is still in dev mode. Your tester could then comment on that post …

Comment: alright, did not know that, thanx!

Comment: @misorude Just want to clarify. Assumed I get the access token from our Facebook page admin of our Production Facebook page (it is also the app admin) and used in app dev mode.

Is it still valid for the est content is visible to app tester and the people with a role in my app IF  app tester leaves the comment at EXISTING Production Facebook page?

Comment: In order to receive real events from webhook for my Production Facebook page, I need to turn my production app go live.

Can I use the test app (in development mode) at the same time to facebook inbox to the user who leave the specific comments on my Facebook post? Is the comment invisible to other?

Comment: If you create a post via an app that is in dev mode, that post will only be visible to people with a role in the app. Any comments made on that post, “inherit” that post’s visibility - anyone who can’t see the post in the first place, won’t see any comments either. (But you might want to remember to remove those test posts before you set the app live then.) But working with a combination of a live app and an app in dev mode, that combo likely won’t work.

Comment: @misorude

Noted, thanks for great explanation.

I think I will just use production app with live mode to perform live test. Just pick some old post to test it.